# SoapFault Exception When Calling NAV Webservice

Tags: java, web-services, soapfault

How may I get rid of the following error :

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: The Element <Student_Registration_Detail> is expected by Min Occurs value: Once. Element received: <ns10:Student_Registration_Detail>.
```

The method call I make is defined by a webservice and I pass in my arguments using objects created using the provided ObjectFactory object. I cannot for the life of me see why the "ns10:" is being added to the Holder object.

Regards

Comment: could you share SOAP request XML?

Comment: When I marshall the object, it does not contain the "ns10" part.  Currently I am not even writing the object to file. Also the error seems to be random. Sometimes the request goes through and sometimes it doesn't. Should I still share the marshalled object